# Parse Twitter.Status into String

Tags: java, android, twitter

I am Integrating Twitter API with Android using

```
twitter4j-core-android-2.2.6.jar
```

I successfully fetch UserName, Profile Picture and other stuff but facing some problem while fetching Status(tweet). Following is the code i used to fetch tweet (Status).

```
User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
Status s = user.getStatus();
Log.d("Status",  ""+s.toString());
```

But the response is not in readable format, How to convert that is string. Following is the Logcat results foe above statement.

```
01-23 15:30:28.062: E/Status(8534): Testing app...  
http://*********', source='<a href="http://www.facebook.com/twitter" 
rel="nofollow">Facebook</a>', isTruncated=false,  
geoLocation=null, place=null, retweetCount=0, wasRetweetedByMe=false, 
contributors=null, annotations=null, retweetedStatus=null, 
userMentionEntities=[], urlEntities=[URLEntityJSONImpl{start=116, 
end=136, url=**************************************************, 
displayURL=***************}], hashtagEntities=[], user=null}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with ``twitter4j`` but there exists a method ``Status.getText()`` which may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Glad to see Your response. Yeah Harism m looking for something like Status.getText() but this method didn't exists in twitter4j

Comment: Ah, I see, are we looking at the same documentation; http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/2.2.6/twitter4j/Status.html ?

Comment: Ahan, Let me explore something from that link :-)

Comment: Just a reminder: twitter4j 2.2.6 is an old version for Twitter API 1.0 - Twitter will discontinue the support of this API soon. You will have to update twitter4j to a 3.x version if you still want to be able to connect to twitter